# Does Ghostscript use AES or DES encryption method when encrypting PDFs?

Tags: pdf, encryption, aes, ghostscript, des

Does Ghostscript use AES or DES  encryption method when encrypting PDFs?
Do I need to specify a specific -dEncriptionR=# value (# can be 2, 3, 4, 5, etc) to use AES as opposed to DES on the Ghostscript command line?

Answer (score 1):

The pdfwrite device in Ghostscript does not support AES or DES when encrypting output, it only supports the Standard method.

The EncryptionR switch only controls which revision of the standard security handler is used and it has only two values 2 or 3, as described in gs/ps2pdf.htm and in the PDF reference manual (Table 3.19 on p 122 in my copy of the 1.7 reference)